How to solve state file related error when there is mismatch in checksum?
We were getting below error while performing the "terraform plan"
Error: error loading state: state data in S3 does not have the expected content. │ The checksum calculated for the state stored in S3 does not match the checksum │ stored in DynamoDB. │ │ Bucket: bucketname │ Key:    path/terraform.tfstate │ Calculated checksum: │ Stored checksum:     xxshjkxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
This happened due to state file deletion or corruption.

Do any of answers listed here help?
